# how to select new instance of object with another fields in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, instance

assume that i have these calsses:

```
public class A {
    public Long id;
    public B b;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;  
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public B getB() {
        return b;  
    }
}

public class B {
    public Long id;
    public String code;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;  
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public Long getCode() {
        return code;  
    }


    public B(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and i want to execute this query:

```
select new B(a.b.id) as b, a.b.code as bCode
from A a
```

but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select new B(b1.id) as b, b1.code as bCode
from A a
inner join a.b as b1
```